# regex to find hyphenated text in java

Tags: java, regex

I need find out only hyphenated text like this, i made some code for this its working but it has some problem.

Eg:-(PRX)-is a non-steroidal surface-to-volume-ratio-due-to-the characterized-by a poorly water solubility.(Key)-words " Only non-steroidal is valid only."

1. **non-steroidal--->valid**(only this type is valid rest all should be neglected
2. **surface-to-volume-ratio-due-to-the---> not valid**
3. **(Key)-words:----> not valid**

only one hyphen is allowed. if there are 2 hyphen in a word then it should be neglected.

my regex is--:

```
(((\b|,|'|.!|)(([a-zA-Z])+){0}-{1}(([a-zA-Z]+))(\b|,|'|.!)))
```

as in this fig: red circle are showing that must be neglected.[image]

Comment: Can you put some sample data for valid and invalid matches?

Comment: Thanks for update your question with sample data it was very useful to help you. You can check my updated answer now

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get **words with only one hyphen** you can use this regex:

```
(?<!-)\b(\w+\-\w+)\b(?!-)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oS9pR2/2)**

[image]

But if you want to get **hyphened words (with multiple hyphens)** you can use:

```
((?:\w+\-)+\w+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oS9pR2/1)**

[image]

Comment: sir its working but kindly check image where i am using regex on html page, if any css contains hyphen then that will also catch in this code so could you solve this problem.

Comment: @SNPrasadRao I'm not fully sure what you need. Can you add a text marking what hyphen words you don't want to match?

Comment: sir your regex is working perfectly just to neglect the word which is in Id as showing in image,which is red circle.I am adding an image in your answer kindly check it.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for help.

[^"](?<!-)\b([a-zA-Z]+\-[a-zA-Z]+)\b(?!-)

Comment: @SNPrasadRao glad to help you. If my answer helped you answering your question you could consider it mark it as solved :)